# How to send data from all the checked radio buttons from a modal window to the parent's controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal-dialog, radio-button

I got this problem

In the mainController I declared a list of ids, called allUsers, I send them to the modal window to be displayed with a radio button, each radio button has a different name, to enable the multiple selection, but all have the same ng-model, selectedUsers, that is.

Once I select a few of the displayed users, I press the OK button, who triggers the $scope.ok function, there in a for loop i wanna get all the users I selected, and push them in a list, selectedUserIds.

But, once I run the code, my selectedUsers list is empty (but i selected 3 users)

So, in the end, there are two possible problems.

1. My code for the radio buttons and getting data from them is wrong
2. I don't even send the data from the modal window to the main controller

I hope you can help me...

here is the code:

mainController.js

```
        $scope.allUsers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
        $scope.selectedUserIds = [];

        $scope.ok = function() {
            angular.forEach($scope.selectedUsers, function(user) {
                $scope.selectedUserIds.push(user);
            });
        }


        $scope.open = function () {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            scope: $scope,                  
            templateUrl: '../Popup.html',
            resolve: {
                    allUsers: function() {
                        return $scope.allUsers;
                    }                       
                  }
            });

        }
```

index.html

```
<button ng-click="open()">Share Script</button>
```

Popup.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Share the Script</h3>
</div>


<div class="modal-body">
<h4>Check the users who you want to share the selected script!</h4>
<ul>
    <label ng-repeat="user in allUsers"> 
    <input type="radio" name={{user}} ng-value="{{user}}" ng-model="selectedUsers"
    /> {{user}} user
    </label>

</ul>



</div>


<div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="ok();$close()">Ok</button>
     <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$close()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend setting up [pen](http://codepen.io/)/[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)/[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue).

Comment: I can try, but all I could do was this, and it does not the same functionality as the described code above.....in fact it is not working at all, and i have no idea why......(1st time on plunker)  .....    https://plnkr.co/edit/aSQsetlSuKlxYNpHMxCf?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and I will post it here, if someone has the same problem as me....

mainController

```
    $scope.allUsers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    $scope.selectedUserIds = [];

    $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        scope: $scope,
        controller: 'modalController'       //<<<<<here is a new controller
        templateUrl: '../Popup.html',
        resolve: {
                allUsers: function() {
                    return $scope.allUsers;
                }                       
              }
        });

       //add here the code to receive the data
       //look bellow, and read the answer

    }
```

modalController

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
//side note, the main controller belongs to myApp module as well

myApp.controller('modalController', function($scope, $uibModalInstance,
    $modalInstance, users) {

$scope.items = users;
$scope.selectedUsers = [];

$scope.addUsersToList = function(users) {
    //not finished
    //add the users from the selected radio buttons to a list
    //lets call the list: $scope.finalList
}

$scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.finalList); //here u send back the data
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

});

then in the mainController, you need to be ready to receive the data

```
 modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedUsers) {
      $scope.selectedUsers.push(selectedUsers);  //here you get the data from the moduleController
}, function () {
      console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
 });
```

this code, you need to add to the above marked place
--> //add here the code to receive the data

Then you can do whatever you want :)